# Digital Circuit Design

Tags: computer-science

Design and implement a digital circuit which will detect a 4 bit number which is less than 3 or greater than 12 or divisible by 3 (if conditions are met, the output is 1, 0 otherwise). Implement the circuit with NAND only logic gate.

I've derived a truth table to it which looks like this:
[image]

But in the example that my professor showed in class, he was able to have outputs such as W,X,Y,Z. From there he derived the circuit with the output. I seem to be stuck on the very first step because I am not sure how to translate this truth table to have results in the form of WXYZ. It seems like I only have one end result.

Comment: They are just symbols, they might mean whatever your professor wanted them to mean. I suspect X,Y,Z would be "input<3", "input>12" and "divisible by 3" in your truth table. Then W would be the result, which is equal to $X\lor Y\lor Z$. 

Also, if you want to simplify things a bit, notice that the table is symmetric.

Comment: I just realized the fact that the circuit could only have one output. Which I think is the case here. And wow, I did not notice the symmetry. That's really interesting! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic

Use this for constructing any gate - AND/OR/EXOR etc.  As far as your equation goes, it simplifies to
A.B + A'B' + A'.B.C.D' + A.B'.C'.D where . refers to AND gate, + refers to OR gate and ' refers to NOT.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot how useful something as simple as wikepedia can be!